# How to use php inside JS in a php file

Tags: javascript, php

I have a php file in which i have added JS inside echo.
I want to use php function inside that JS scope now, how can i do that:

```
<?php
  echo '<script>
    <?php 
      function message() {
        echo "You will be redirected";
      } 
    ?>
    setTimeout(<?php message();>?,3000);</script>';
?>
```

Comment: you have to make apart the client and server code and their difference.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question has very low quality.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: A quick, ugly hack would be rendering Javascript directly with PHP and setting header manually.

Comment: @KrisRoofe That's not a valid close reason for being off-topic. Please vote for an actual close reason.

Comment: You can't call a PHP (or other server-side language) function from inside client JS. You can use PHP functions to help generate the JS.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: Please try making an API for the same and hit it .. this is the height! Come on :D

Answer (score 0):

PHP will execute first, on the server, so you would have to code it in a .php file, to ensure the server runs it through PHP, then have it embed the PHP in the JavaScript like so:

```
<script>
function message(){
    alert("<?= $phpMessage ?>");
    location.href = "http://www.example.com" /* The URL you would like the user to go to next */;
}
setTimeout(message,3000);
</script>
```

Assuming you want to display a message from PHP, you may embed it in an alert statement as <?= $phpMessage ?>.  This will be awkward for your users.

A more graceful solution would be to use session storage to pass a message to the next page.

On the page that is receiving the data and needs to send a message, the first PHP command, before any output is sent should be **session_start()**.  A message may be saved in a session variable with **$_SESSION['message']** and it will be available for the next script, like so:

**one.php** (first page)

```
<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['message'] = 'My Message';
```

**two.php** (second page)

```
<?php session_start(); echo $_SESSION['message']; unset($_SESSION['message']); ?>
```

Notice that the second script must use **unset** to clear the message.

Comment: Maybe, he could put in inline PHP file or basically render the file with PHP (and setting header manually).

Answer (score 0):

No matter what you do, JavaScript can't execute your PHP in the context of a page. Based on your example, I don't think you'd want to do that in PHP anyway.

If you just want to output a message before redirecting a user, JavaScript alone is the right tool for the job:

```
<script>
  function message() {
    document.write("You will be redirected");
  } 
  setTimeout(message,3000);
</script>
```

I'm trying to think of a scenario in which it would make sense to mix PHP and JavaScript like you asked about, but I can't.

However, if you really insist...

```
<?php
  function message() {
    return "You will be redirected";
  }

  echo '
    <script>
      setTimeout(() => document.write("' . message() . '"), 3000);
    </script>
  ';
 ?>
```

Tested at https://repl.it/GF2E/0

Note that the JavaScript arrow function syntax is [supported by all current browsers](http://caniuse.com/#feat=arrow-functions).